# React Navigation Header in Functional Components with Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-native, header, react-navigation

I am trying to inject custom headers to React functional components that are using Hooks.

So for example I have the following React functional component with some hooks:

```
function StoryHome(props) {
  const [communityObj, setCommunityObj] = useState({
    uid: null,
    name: null,
  });
...
}

StoryHome.navigationOptions = {
  title: 'Stories',
  headerTitleStyle: {
    textAlign: 'left',
    fontFamily: 'OpenSans-Regular',
    fontSize: 24,
  },
  headerTintColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.8)',
  headerBackground: (
    <LinearGradient
      colors={['#4cbdd7', '#3378C3']}
      start={{ x: 0, y: 1 }}
      end={{ x: 1, y: 1 }}
      style={{ flex: 1 }}
    />
  ),
  headerRightContainerStyle: {  
    paddingRight: 10,   
  },    
  headerRight: (    
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={navigation.navigate('storiesList')}> 
      <Ionicons 
         name="ios-search-outline"  
         size={25}  
         color="white"  
         left={20}  
       />   
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
};

export default StoryHome;
```

So this sort of works, except with the `TouchableOpacity` part.

First, I don't get the `Ionicon` to render correctly and second, I don't have access to the `navigation` object outside of the functional component.

I would love to continue using Hooks but can't seem to figure this one out.

Comment: How did you add this StoryHome in the createStackNavigator?

Comment: Like this:

`export const StoryNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  StoryHome: { screen: StoryHome },
  StoryDetail: { screen: StoryDetail },
  StoryList: { screen: StoryList },
});`

Comment: if you are using navigation 4 : 
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/upgrading-from-4.x/#specifying-navigationoptions-for-a-screen

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`navigationOptions` can be a function that gets an object as argument with `navigation` as a property.

You also need to make sure you give a function to `onPress`, and that you don't invoke `navigation.navigate` directly.

```
StoryHome.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
  title: "Stories",
  headerTitleStyle: {
    textAlign: "left",
    fontFamily: "OpenSans-Regular",
    fontSize: 24
  },
  headerTintColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.8)",
  headerBackground: (
    <LinearGradient
      colors={["#4cbdd7", "#3378C3"]}
      start={{ x: 0, y: 1 }}
      end={{ x: 1, y: 1 }}
      style={{ flex: 1 }}
    />
  ),
  headerRightContainerStyle: {
    paddingRight: 10
  },
  headerRight: (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("storiesList")}>
      <Ionicons name="ios-search" size={25} color="white" left={20} />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much, the navigation part worked perfectly! The only thing that's not working is the `Ionicons` part. I am getting `failed prop type invalid prop name`.

Comment: @esfoobar Great! You're welcome. I'm not sure how to use the Ionic icons in React Native. The documentation might help you figure out what props there are.

Comment: Thanks so much. Looks like that icon name doesn't exist on the Ionicon implementation of that react native library. Changed it to `ios-search` and it worked. Again thank you!

Comment: What if I want to pass a hook state in the ```StoryHome``` component in the ```navigationOptions```. How can we do that ?